# I want to use Similar Pop UP Styles as shown in this website

Tags: javascript, css

I want to create popup windows similar to as shown in this web site .
http://yensdesign.com/2008/09/how-to-create-a-stunning-and-smooth-popup-using-jquery/

Try the Online example here 
http://yensdesign.com/tutorials/popupjquery/

This is the code that is responsible to display the POPUP WINDOW .

```
<html> 
<head>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="general.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.2.6.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var popupStatus = 0;

    function loadPopup(){

if(popupStatus==0){
$("#backgroundPopup").css({
"opacity": "0.7"
});
$("#backgroundPopup").fadeIn("slow");
$("#popupContact").fadeIn("slow");
popupStatus = 1;
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
                <div id="button"><input type="submit" value="Press me please!"  onclick="loadPopup();"/></div>
    </center>
    <div id="popupContact">
        Hi 
    </div>
    <div id="backgroundPopup"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Here the author is displaying a  Pop Up Window . What I want is that i already have an existing page (Charts.html) which I want to show as POP UP Window with similar style , is that possible?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show Charts.html in an iframe.

Comment: Just put an iframe inside popupContact.

Comment: Thank you very much . Its absolutely fine .

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely - and if you want to make it really easy, you chould just put charts.html in an iFrame with for example fancybox ( http://fancybox.net/howto check under 4 -> iFrame ). Then you could just style the css to fit your site. You could of course do the same thing with the code at the site you showed.